# SQL Duplicate column names error in Create View, even with aliases

Tags: sql-server, oracle

The error is oddly specific, but I've just about honed in where it's occurring. The standard fix doesn't seem to be working though.

Here's where the error occurs. It's a big statement, so I'm just posting where I've found the error

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SalesInvoiceDoc 
 AS 
 ( SELECT si.salinv_Num, si.salinv_Terms, si.salinv_SaleDate, 
          es.empName AS SalesAgent, man.empName AS ApprovingManager,
          si.salinv_ApproveDate, ...

 ... FROM service_invoice si
 JOIN employee es
    ON (es.empID = si.salinv_EmpID)
 JOIN employee man
    ON (man.empID = si.salinv_ManID)
```

Essentially it's a Sales invoice document with a sales agent and approving manager. Both are stored in the employee table with a subtype discriminator set up for 'manager' or 'sales', and views for the subtype children tables to avoid duplication errors.

I've supplied aliases to try and avoid duplicate columns, but when I run this script, I get the duplicate column names error:

```
ORA-00957: duplicate column name
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Is it even possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Edit: here's the full statement

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SalesInvoiceDoc
 AS
 ( SELECT si.salinv_Num, si.salinv_Terms, si.salinv_SaleDate,
    es.empName AS SalesAgent,
    man.empName AS ApprovingManager, si.salinv_ApproveDate,
    sc.custName, sc.custHouse, sc.custCity, 
    sc.custState, sc.custZIP, sc.custPhone, sc.custEmail,
    sv.vehicle_VIN, sv.vehicle_year, sv.vehicle_make, 
        sv.vehicle_model, sv.vehicle_ext_color, sv.vehicle_trim,
        sv.vehicle_list_base_price, sv.vehicle_mileage, sv.vehicle_condition,
        sv.vehicle_description,
     ti.vehicle_make, ti.vehicle_year, ti.vehicle_model, ti.vehicle_VIN, 
        ti.tradein_allowance,
    sv.vehicle_list_base_price "SellingPrice", sv.shipping "Shipping",
        ti.tradein_allowance "TradeAllowance",
(sv.vehicle_list_base_price + sv.shipping - ti.tradein_allowance) "Subtotal",
(sv.vehicle_list_base_price + sv.shipping - ti.tradein_allowance)*.0825 "Taxes",
(sv.vehicle_list_base_price + sv.shipping - ti.tradein_allowance)*1.0825 "TotalSellingPrice"

 FROM sales_invoice si
JOIN employee es
    ON (es.empID = si.salinv_EmpID)
JOIN employee man
    ON (man.empID = si.salinv_ManID)
JOIN customer sc
    ON (sc.custID = si.salinv_CustID)
JOIN vehicle sv
    ON (sv.vehicle_VIN = si.salinv_SalVIN)
LEFT OUTER JOIN vehicle ti
    ON (ti.vehicle_VIN = si.salinv_tiVIN)
 );
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server, or perhaps Oracle?

Comment: Edited tag `Oracle` seeing the error `ORA-00957`. Tag properly in future

Comment: `create view viewname (colname1, colname2, ...) ...`

Comment: It's apex oracle sql server

Comment: @jarlh, that shouldn't matter actually.

Comment: Post the entire create view statement and not partially

Comment: Sorry @Rahul, first time posting here

Comment: You have vehicle make, year and model and VIN in there twice.. once from the ti table once from the sv table

Comment: Lol yes I do @NickDewitt! God so simple... I've been staring at this too long. Thanks for providing a second set of eyes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are duplicating column names from 2 different tables:

```
sv.vehicle_VIN, 
sv.vehicle_year, 
sv.vehicle_make, 
sv.vehicle_model
```

and

```
ti.vehicle_make, 
ti.vehicle_year, 
ti.vehicle_model, 
ti.vehicle_VIN
```

The resulting column name does not include the table alias.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is cause `sv.vehicle_VIN` is appearing twice in your query and so does other columns. See below. You need to alias them all accordingly

```
**sv.vehicle_VIN**, **sv.vehicle_year**, **sv.vehicle_make**,  **sv.vehicle_model**, 

     **ti.vehicle_make**, **ti.vehicle_year**, **ti.vehicle_model**, **ti.vehicle_VIN**,
```